# Create Alarm in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am having difficulty passing Load Balancer info when creating alarm in CloudFormation.

```
RequestCountHigh:
   Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
   Properties:
    AlarmDescription: Scale up 
    MetricName: RequestCount
    Namespace: AWS/ApplicationELB
    Statistic: Average
    Period: 300
    EvaluationPeriods: 1
    Threshold: 2
    AlarmActions: [!Ref ScaleUpPolicy]
    Dimensions:
      - Name: LoadBalancer 
        Value: !Ref WebAppALB    
    ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
```

It is passing Load Balancer information in format: `arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:932921245520:loadbalancer/app/Appro-WebAp-1MH0X13S89TO8/b2f9795447cbxxxx`

Instead of in format `app/Appro-WebAp-1MH0X13S89TO8/b2f9795447cbxxxx`

This causes Alarm to be in INSUFFICIENT state. Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `WebAppALB` is a [`AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html), `!Ref WebAppALB` returns the ARN of the load balancer.

You probably need `!GetAtt WebAppALB.LoadBalancerFullName` instead. Please check the documentation on [return values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html#aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer-return-values) of `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer`.